# I've got an error in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I am new to swift 3 and now I've got an error that I couldnt find the answer for...
I want to make a table view in my custom design and the part taht I wanted to register my xib file.

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  Flash Chat

import UIKit
import Firebase

class ChatViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var sendButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var messageTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var messageTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        messageTableView.delegate = self
        messageTableView.dataSource = self

        messageTableView.register(UINib(nibName : "MessageCell" , Bundle : nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomMessageCell
        let messageArray = ["First Message", "Second Message", "Third Message"]
        cell.messageBody.text = messageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {  
        return 3  
    }

    @IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func logOutPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {    
        do {
            try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()    
        } catch {   
            print(error)     
        }

        guard (navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)) != nil
            else {
                print("ther is no view controller")
                return
        }
    }
}
```

[image: error Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the typo mistake , the Initializer called in **init(nibName:bundle:)** not **init(nibName:Bundle:)**

is

```
      messageTableView.register(UINib(nibName : "MessageCell" , bundle : nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")
```

or use

```
 messageTableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "MessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")
```

not

```
       messageTableView.register(UINib(nibName : "MessageCell" , Bundle : nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @sasansoroush - welcome my bro, accept any one answer

Answer (score 0):

The second argument label must be 'bundle', not 'Bundle,' see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinib/1614135-init.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo in UINib initialization, replace

```
UINib(nibName : "MessageCell" , Bundle : nil)
```

with

```
UINib(nibName : "MessageCell" , bundle : nil)
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Correct this

```
 messageTableView?.register(UINib.init(nibName: "MessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your cell registration statement to the following:

```
messageTableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "MessageCell",
                                       bundle: nil),
                            forCellReuseIdentifier: "customMessageCell") //Just copy-paste this
```

You have used wrong method argument labels for the `UINib` constructor. Changing `Bundle` to `bundle` will work. Typo.

Comment: Welcome. @sasansoroush